# pandas plot transformed column defined only inside the plot command

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Is it possible to make plot of a column by just defining the simple operation on the plot command? An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2),columns=list('AB'))
df.plot(x='A',y='B',kind='scatter')
```

When I try the following instead, it doesnt do the operation directly in the plot and gives an error. I know one can routinely define the transformed column outside and then plot it, however I am curious if it is possible just inside the plot command?

```
df.plot(x='A',y='B'**0.8 +1,kind='scatter') # to plot B^0.8+1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not.  Python interprets `'B'**0.8 + 1` before the plot command even sees it

Comment: @PaulH What would be then the most pythonic way to do it without adding the new transformed col to df? Thanks!

Comment: I would use a chained command: `ax = df.assign(y=df['B'] ** 0.8 + 1).plot(x='A', y=y, kind='scatter')`. Your original dataframe won't contain the "y" column

Comment: Thanks. If you could write this as Answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Might be helpful for others.